# Let $n$ be a 3-digit number. Prove $9\mid n$ iff the digits of $n$ sum to a multiple of 9.

Tags: number-theory

I have convinced myself that this true, however I'm at a loss of where I should start with this proof. Looking at a similar proof with 3 instead of 9, I saw the use of the basis representation theorem, but I'm not 100% comfortable with that, so it was hard for me to follow. Is there a way to do this with mod?

Comment: This holds for *all* $n$, not just three-digit numbers. The proof isn't too hard, and, yes, it does include modular arithmetic.

Comment: If you're only concerned about 3-digit numbers, you can just check them one by one, since that's a small, finite set. But you'd be missing out on a proof of the general case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $10\equiv1\pmod{9}    $.

Answer (score 0):

let $z=a_0+10a_1+100a_2\equiv a_0+a_1+a_2 \mod 9$